# Can I host the Visual Studio 2010 editor in my application?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am wondering whether it's feasible to host the Visual Studio 2010 editor in my WPF application - I understand the new editor is written in WPF.

If so, what control should I use?

Comment: I would assume that would depend on whether Microsoft even publishes the VS editor as a standalone control.  Have you done any research into this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an answer to your exact question (though I would bet that hosting part of vs.net isn't readily supported or licensed)...

SharpDevelop makes their code editor, [Avalon Edit](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/Default.aspx?Page=AvalonEdit&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1), available as a standalone. I'm using the beta WPF version and it is quite nice. It's got configurable syntax highlighting and auto completion support.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that this is not supported in Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Studio 2008.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsldesigner/pages/general-wpf-and-silverlight-designer-faq.aspx item 5.

Thanks
Mark Wilson-Thomas
Program Manager, WPF & Silverlight Designer Team, Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Not all of the Microsoft applications is based on the available-to-all controls. I don't see any reason, why the VS2010 should be the exclusion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the SharpDevelop one is probably the best option, however you could also look at [ScintillaNET](http://www.codeplex.com/ScintillaNET). This is used by MyGeneration and it very configurable.