# Host Visual Studio Core Editor as a standalone editor Control inside WPF app

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2022, code-editor

I want to host Visual Studio Core Editor as a standalone editor inside my C# WPF app. At present I am using [AvalonEdit](https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit) in the project. I want some more features and more sophisticated editor. Is it possible to create an instance of Visual Studio Core Editor and host inside WPF app ?

I found some related posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083585/which-wpf-element-was-used-for-the-visual-studio-code-editor), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948361/can-i-host-the-visual-studio-2010-editor-in-my-application), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935951/create-instance-of-visual-studio-editor-control-in-net), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440224/i-would-like-to-place-a-visual-studio-code-editor-in-a-direct-x-window-is-this). But they are too old and Microsoft has already published [vs-editor-api](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-editor-api/tree/e18c94faf05810839740314da6388365596ac0b9). Is it possible to use this API to create an Editor inside our app ?